# Android UI Automation: Subscribe to Android Events

Tags: android, ui-automation

Is there a way to subscribe to events from an installed app on a AVD? What I would like to do is, e.g., when I enter any text on a EditText field in the app, I want to automatically receive a notification in my program, with the details (entered value). Is there any way I can subscribe to the android app events from any installed apk ? If there are frameworks or any Android native drivers which can do this, please mention them.

Comment: You might want to explain your background a little. The scenario you are describing seems as if you want to develop a keylogger, and I don't think you will get any helpful answers as long as that seems to be the tenor of your question.

Comment: @Romiox No, this is not for a keylogger, but for automated testing of  a native android app. With a program I can provide inputs for a native app, click on buttons in the app, etc. I would also like to capture user interaction so that when a user selects a field, clicks on buttons, I can do further processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to do something similar via Android's accessibility API. You'd need to write an [Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html) which would need to be installed and then explicitly enabled via the control panel (this is a security precaution to prevent arbitrary apps getting access to potentially sensitive contents of UI of other apps). Your service can listen to [AccessibilityEvents](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#events) - looks like [TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent.html#TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) event -  "Represents the event of changing the text of an EditText" - is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/) for Android

Comment: Thanks Uriel. This would need modification of the source code of the app. I do not have access to the source for the app. I would like to automate the UI testing of any installed app. Is there any way where source code modification is not needed? Installing any global event listener for example, which will work across all apps installed on the AVD?